# Highcharts to get Combined Bar and line charts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i would like to ask is that possible using Highcharts to get Combined Bar and line charts?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You just have to provide different series with corresponding types like in

```
series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
    },  {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Average',
        data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
    }]
```

See http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo